# AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'get_xtickabels'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I.m trying to make a heat map with two axes and wants to have the top axis labels to show on 'top'. Therefore, I tried to make a list of the ticks so that I can set the ticks later but I run into the following issue

**AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'get_xtickabels'**

my code does it as follows
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIvPt.png)

I use the python interpreter provided by the PyCharm

[python interpriter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhLlo.png)

and I'm confused what raises this issue as I have installed latest Matplotlib version within. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a [code typo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticklabels.html). Next time, please do not post images of code/error messages/data. Post the text directly here on SO.

Comment: Thank you Mr.T, sure will post the text in future.

Answer (score 0):

you wrote 'ax1.get_xtickables' instead of 'ax1.get_xticklabels'.

Comment: Thank you @David Camp, it fixed the issue!